# Calculating 95% confidence Interval, without R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model

For my exam we are given extracts of data from R, usually with a summary and ANOVA table. From there a question that often comes up is to calculate a 95% confidence interval for a given variable. I know the formulae is something like:

standard  deviation  of variable $*$ t-value(degrees of freedom, 0.975) $\pm $ estimate of the variable.

What I am unsure on is how we find the standard deviation of our variable from the summary and ANOVA tables.

I'm fairly new to R and had a very bad teacher so forgive me if this is a stupid question

Comment: You need the standard error of the estimate where you have written standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks so much! Just figured it out as you posted this